# Is it possible to damage or target Fiora during her ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

When Fiora uses her ultimate what is the correct response, assuming there is no tower nearby? According to the champion spotlight the best course of action is to run toward the tower to cause her to appear next to it when the ultimate finishes. However, if there is no tower is it possible to target or damage her? I don't really like my current strategy of sitting there and waiting till I can resume the fight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do, is use some aoe, she can't be targetted by the enemy team but she can still get damage from persistent aoe. For example Morgana's aoe pool, while dancing around in the pool it can still damage her. Aoe slows will work aswell since when she stops waltzing she might be slowed making it easyer to kill her. Thus in team fights you might die but your team will be able to kill the squishy dancer.(I'm not sure but maybe for example Ziggs can still lay down his minefield, and she may hit em while waltzing.)

P.s. noticed this last night but towers still fire on her while waltzing... don't know if this is a bug of planned. Anyway the official website sais not targeted by enemy team, it doesn't say anything about towers.

Edit: You can also spread out and take the full force of the ultimate, since it does less damage the second hit she does. I think it is 25% the next attack on the target. Or you can stand close to eachother with 4 and let others tank a few hits but they will take 100% damage the first hit so that might not be so good.

Comment: What about morgana throwing her Q to her and (by a huge amount of luck) hitting her while she's waltzing? Will fiora get imprisoned and immobilized (thus stopping her waltz)?

Comment: @Eregrith It could be, but i don't know haven't seen so much luck yet. But what i think would happen is she doesn't stop waltzing but finishes the ulti then stops

Answer (score 3):

According to her information page on the [official League of Legends website](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions/114/fiora_the_grand_duelist):

> Blade Waltz not only deals damage, it also prevents you from being targeted by the enemy team.

So, as sad as it is to say, I fear your strategy may be the only option.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

As it shows in Rift Myths, Fiora **CAN** be targeted by Shen while in her ultimate.

And Jax Can avoid Fiora's ultimate too.

Also Akali cancels Fiora's ultimate when she enter in her shroud.

---

[Spotlight by Phreak](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVjARs53CVw)
At 04:02 he start a team fight and quote this "Once I get low, I target her (Ashe) with Blade Waltz. It takes me out of combat, so I stop taking damage..."

When you use Blade Waltz you dash to the target, like when Maokai use Twisted advance. If the person use flash Fiora will follow the target until he stops. This is why he advise you to jump to near some turret, so when Fiora land (after Blade Waltz) she will be hitted by turret.

You can Flash to your allies, will work as good as the turret.

Good strategy:

2. Stay near/flash to your turret/alies. When her ult finish she will be in BIG troble. The problem in jump to your allies is, they will get damage from her ult, so be careful.
3. Use [Zhonya's Hourglass](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/items#3157) until her ult finish. You will avoid the damage from it.
4. If you are nunu, you can start your ult, when her ult finish, your ult will be probably near to end, then BOOM =)

Comment: Zhonya's Hourglass is not a good item for her, since she is mostly AD champion.

Comment: @nimcap He meant that you can use the Hourglass when a Fiora is doing her ultimate to you.

Comment: @Marcelo: oh thanks! I totally misread the whole thing!

Comment: If you are alone zhonya's will work, but if you are with a team i think she will just flip around and attack another untill the last hit, but since you already got the first attack the last one only does 25% damage, so that would mean that you avoided 25% of her damage. And you've done non in return for 2 sec.

Comment: @Lyrion Works if you are VERY low, and 1 hit point Matters =)

Comment: @MichelAyres True but it can backfire, if you are very low and she is still around and untargetable for the second she waltzes she might still kill you

Answer (score 2):

Sona's Q (Hymn of Valor) can hit her during her Ultimate. I've done it before.

Comment: Hi Renshin, and welcome to Arqade! Since this is your first post, here is some advice. Your answer is fine, but lacks a bit of depth. See other answers and try contributing to them. If you "have done it before", then it might be not a bad idea to include an illustration or even a video describing how.

Answer (score 0):

Consider purchasing [Zhonya's Hourglass](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zhonya's_Hourglass).  The Hourglass has a shorter CD than [Fiora](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fiora#Blade_Waltz)'s ultimate, and causes her ult to be wasted if no other allies are nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Turrets can and will target Fiora during her ult. However, it can't lock on long enough to fire because it loses her again when she disappears so you'll notice the turret locks on each time she appears during the ult but will never get a shot off until she lands at the end. It's one of the reasons she dangerous even under your turret. She great at diving when her ult is up. As far as AOE goes, yea, it can hurt her in the ult as will any targeted damage over time that she received before the ult started. As was stated above, some champions can cancel the ult. Anyone with a hard cc aoe such as annie or amumu will pull her out of it for example. I'm not sure about the aoe dots for the most part such as Morgana's pool as was said above, but I know she doesn't hit Ziggs mines until she comes out of the ult (assuming he's standing in them.) You don't really want to consider going 1v1 on her with ziggs though. I don't think I've ever seen that come out well for the bomber in the end - at least not when I play her. Anyway, best advice, hard aoe cc. Fiora's worst enemy. If you lock her down the fight is over. She's soft. Some people like to build a warmog on her (not me usually) but even that won't offer much protection against a team dedicated to her destruction.